# Python3 print statement issue when end parameter is used on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I am testing the following code on macOS Monetery version 12.1. The print statement does not print anything on the terminal when I use end = " " in the statement. Can anybody explain why this is happening? This code runs fine on Windows.

```
class Squares:
   def __init__(self, start, stop) -> None:
       self.start = start
       self.stop = stop


   def __iter__(self,):
       for i in range(self.start, self.stop +1):
           yield i ** 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    S = Squares(1, 3)
    for i in S:
       for j in S:
          print(f'{i}:{j}', end= " ", flush=True)
```

But if add a print statement after the for loops the results are printed on the terminal.

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        S = Squares(1, 3)
        for i in S:
           for j in S:
              print(f'{i}:{j}', end= " ", flush=True)
        print()
```

Output: [No output from the print function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obTvJ.png)

Output2: [Output when empty print is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3Lmb.png)

PS: Sorry for the black boxes I had to redact personal information.

Comment: Adding the empty `print()` causes a newline to be output — so that seems likely to be what's fixing it. My guess is it's just a subtle difference between the OSs (or maybe the way a terminal console is being emulated on them).

Comment: I am using zsh on MacOS and the moment I changed to bash the script worked normally. May be the zsh has some issues but I am not able to find a single document where this issue is listed.

Comment: It may not be documented because no one has ever noticed and reported it — what you're doing isn't commonly done.